# Android START_NOT_STICKY not working

Tags: android, service, restart

i am trying to write a sample Android service code to test whether , the service stop itself or not after returning START_NOT_STICKY  to onStartCommand. But i whenever , i closed my app , the service stop itself , whereas according to the rule START_NOT_STICKY will not allow to stop the service automatically.

**MyCode :**

**ServiceDemo.java**

```
package com.example.servicedemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent in = new Intent(this,TrackService.class);

    startService(in);


}}
```

**TrackService.java**

```
package com.example.servicedemo;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

 public class TrackService extends Service
{

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags , int startId)
{

    return START_NOT_STICKY;


}

@Override
public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent)
{

    return super.onUnbind(intent);

}}
```

this my above code , whenever i close my app , the app service stops itself , please help me out , how can i restrict my service to stop or restart itself.

Comment: "whenever i close my app" -- how are you doing this?

Comment: close my app means , pressing home and from slide menu swipe up app to close completely....

Answer (score 1):

> close my app means , pressing home and from slide menu swipe up app to close completely

That means that you are terminating your background process. At that point, your service is gone, and since you are returning `START_NOT_STICKY`, it will not automatically restart.

In other words, what is happening is perfectly normal.

Comment: so then , what a service means all about ... how can we keep the service running , if we close the app...

Comment: @user3976029: "how can we keep the service running , if we close the app" -- you don't. The process is terminated. However, if you use `START_STICKY` or `START_REDELIVER_INTENT`, Android will eventually restart your process and restart your service. However, there needs to be a good reason for doing this. [Only have a service running when it is **actively delivering value to the user**](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html).

Comment: No man , you are saying completely irrelevant thing , if i will have phone call app then , do i need to keep open the app always.

Comment: @user3976029: I have no idea what a "phone call app" is.

Answer (score 0):

Close with swipe won't kill this code.

It's a service that runs in the foreground so android treats it as if it is on the screen.  It runs in a seperate process so the main process can be killed.  It shows a custom notification to the user when its running so its completely ligit and it is written.

Note Eclipse ADK Users only put the service in a different process when your done debugging it.

manifest

```
    <service
        android:name="com.gosylvester.bestrides.ServiceLocationRecorder"
           android:process=":myService" >
    </service>
 </application>
```

MyService class

```
private boolean isRecording = false;

public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    boolean isTrackerMarker = SettingMarker.TRACKER_MARKER_DEFAULT;
    if (intent != null) {
        isRecording = intent.getBooleanExtra("isrecording", isRecording);
        startRecording(isRecording);
    }

    //if isRecording keep the service running else let os know service can be killed

    if (isRecording) {
        startForeground(R.id.action_record, getMyCustomNotification());
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    } else {
        stopForeground(true);
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The service **does** get re-created, just **not** re-started.
If you override the `onCreate` and do a Log.d or a Toast, you will see that onCreate gets called after your activity and app is destroyed and even the service `onDestroy` is called.

So the trick to keep it running after it is **re-created** is to put your code on the `onCreate` method and use the `onStartCommand` just to `return START_STICKY`.

Note: onCreate is called before onStartCommand, so your code will run both when it is started by startService and from the system self re-creation.

Comment: if the service has some thread in loop you should stop it by setting some flag used in the loop condition